# MP4 video streaming using Python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to stream a video feed from a webcam in python to render as a texture in Unreal Engine 4.

However, MJPEG is not supported by UE4 so I need my video to be H.264 and encapsulated in MP4 format.

My idea is to use Flask and fetch the video feed with my Unreal app but again I don't know how to serve the video feed in MP4.

The only answers I find are using MJPEG format to stream images from the webcam.